# Why am I getting a warning just for using a tuple?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do some simple vector + tuple exercises, and I'm getting the follow `warning: use of function template name with no prior declaration in function call with explicit template arguments is a C++2a extension`. I don't understand why I'm getting the warning since I've declared both vec and the tuple t? I'm compiling using the follow command `g++ -o vector_practice vector_practice.cpp -std=c++17`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int> > vec;
    vec.insert(vec.begin(), std::tuple("John", 1));

    for (auto t : vec) {
        std::cout << get<0>(t) + " has id of " 
            << get<1>(t) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `std::get`.

Comment: Ah thank you it works!